# Uploading an image on a button click in XMAL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, imagesource

Why this does not load the image?

```
private void OnButtonClickedLoadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ImageSource imgSrc = 
     ImageSource.FromFile("C:\\MyApp\\MyPicture.png");

  ImageViewerc.Source = imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: does your mobile device have a `c:` drive?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: This is running on the desktop for now

Comment: No, it is running in the Android emulator.  Android has no idea what c: is.  If you want to include an image in your app it needs to be part of your project.  Read the docs I linked to

Comment: The image is in your computer but not on your mobile. so it not load the image.

Comment: *Uploading an image on a button click in XMAL* -- just to clarify, should that be ***XAML***?

Comment: Jason - thanks every one. I was locked into so many years of desktop development not realizing that a phone or emulator does NOT have a C: drive. I read the article by Jason and was able to correct the issue - image loads.

Comment: Yes that was supposed to be XAML. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load local images, in Android, Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: AndroidResource. In ios, The preferred way to manage and support images since iOS 9 is to use Asset Catalog Image Sets. Then use Asset Catalog Image Sets. The picture name can get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all (including Jason) for your help. Based on everyone's comment above, I corrected my code to properly load my image like this:

ImageSource imgSrc = ImageSource.FromResource("MyApp.pic2.png", typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

ImageViewerc.Source = imgSrc;

The image must be accessed like this: AppName.ImageFileName.ext  (I was missing the AppName

Also I should note that the character case between the actual file name in Solution Explorer and the code-behind MUST MATCH or image won't load.